# How to give a previous and first links in pagination using AJAX and Codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have given first and last links but confused how to give previous and next links.

```
public function generate_pagination_links()
    {
        $no_of_rows=$this->search_model->search_freelancer_count();
        $limit=1;
        if($no_of_rows > $limit)
        {
            $offset=0;
            $no_of_pagination_links=ceil($no_of_rows/$limit);
            $links="<a onclick='getPage(".$limit.",".$offset.")'>First</a>&nbsp;";
            for($i=1;$i<=$no_of_pagination_links;$i++)
            {
                $links=$links."<a onclick='getPage(".$limit.",".$offset.")'>".$i."</a>&nbsp;";
                $offset=$offset+$limit;
            }
            $offset=$offset-1;
            $links=$links."<a onclick='getPage(".$limit.",".$offset.")'>Last</a>&nbsp;";
            $json=json_encode($links);
            die($json);
        }
        else
        {
            $links="";
            $json=json_encode($links);
            die($json);
        }
    }


//function called on pagination link
    window.getPage = function(limit,offset) {
        //alert('called !');
        var formdata = $( "#simple_searcg" ).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>search/search_freelancer_page/"+limit+"/"+offset,
            dataType: "json",
            data: formdata,
            success: function(result){
                $(".recruiter-search-detail").html("");
                    for(i=0;i<result.length;i++) {
                        var profileimage=result[i].profile_image;
                        var usercom=result[i].user_type+" | "+result[i].company_name;
                        if(profileimage == "demo-profile.png") {
                            profileimage="no_image.png";
                        }
                        if(result[i].user_type == null) {
                            usercom="";
                        }
                        $(".recruiter-search-detail").append("<div class='search-box' id='"+i+"'><div class='image-div col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12'><img id='imgProfile' title='change profile photo' class='profilePic dropzone img-circle' alt='Profile image' src='<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+"upload/profileimage/"+result[i].profile_image+"'></div><div class='recruiter-profile col-lg-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-xs-12'><p class='freelancer-name'><a href='#'>"+result[i].first_name+" "+result[i].last_name+" "+"<span class='usertype'>"+usercom+"</span></a><span class='rate'>$"+result[i].freelancer_rate+"/hr</span></p><p class='professional-title'>"+result[i].professional_title+"<span class='availability'>"+result[i].availability_to_work+"</span></p><p class='location'><i class='fa fa-map-marker'></i>"+result[i].city+", "+result[i].country_name+"</p><p class='overview'>"+result[i].overview+"<a href='#' class='more'>more...</a></p>");
                        $('.search-box').append("<p class='skills'>");
                        var skills1=result[i].skills;
                        var skills = [];
                        skills[i]=skills1.split(', ');
                        for(j=0;j<skills[i].length;j++) {
                            $('#'+i+' '+'.skills').append("<span>"+skills[i][j]+"</span>");
                        }
                        $('.search-box').append("</p></div></div>");
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>search/generate_pagination_links",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: formdata,
                        success: function(page){
                            $(".recruiter-search-detail").append(page);
                        }
                    });
                }
        });
    }
```

> I don't understand how to keep track of current offset used by function to display data.

I am using my own function to paginate the data and I don't use Codeigniter libraries. Any suggestions?

Any one has readymade library for this thing?

(Pagination with ajax in Codeigniter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will make answer too long ( But required. )

Here is a ajax pagination class for codeigniter ( save as lib_ajax_pagination.php in libraries folder ):

```
class Lib_ajax_pagination{

var $base_url           = ''; // The page we are linking to
var $total_rows         = ''; // Total number of items (database results)
var $per_page           = 10; // Max number of items you want shown per page
var $num_links          =  2; // Number of "digit" links to show before/after the currently viewed page
var $cur_page           =  0; // The current page being viewed
var $first_link         = '&lsaquo; First';
var $next_link          = '&gt;';
var $prev_link          = '&lt;';
var $last_link          = 'Last &rsaquo;';
var $uri_segment        = 3;
var $full_tag_open      = '<ul class="pagination">';
var $full_tag_close     = '</ul>';
var $first_tag_open     = '';
var $first_tag_close    = '&nbsp;';
var $last_tag_open      = '&nbsp;';
var $last_tag_close     = '';
var $cur_tag_open       = '&nbsp;<li class="active"><a href="javascript:void();">';
var $cur_tag_close      = '</a></li>';
var $next_tag_open      = '&nbsp;';
var $next_tag_close     = '&nbsp;';
var $prev_tag_open      = '&nbsp;';
var $prev_tag_close     = '';
var $num_tag_open       = '&nbsp;';
var $num_tag_close      = '';

var $js_rebind          = '';
var $div                = '';
var $postVar            = '';
    var $additional_param   = '';

    var $anchor_class       = '';
    var $show_count         = true;
    //added by vijay
    var $start_date         ='';
    var $end_date           ='';
    var $search_val         ='';

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   array   initialization parameters
 */
function CI_Pagination($params = array())
{
    if (count($params) > 0)
    {
        $this->initialize($params);     
    }

    log_message('debug', "Pagination Class Initialized");
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Initialize Preferences
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   array   initialization parameters
 * @return  void
 */
function initialize($params = array())
{
    if (count($params) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($params as $key => $val)
        {
            if (isset($this->$key))
            {
                $this->$key = $val;
            }
        }       
    }

    // Apply class tag using anchor_class variable, if set.
    if ($this->anchor_class != '')
    {
        $this->anchor_class = 'class="' . $this->anchor_class . '" ';
    }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Generate the pagination links
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  string
 */ 
function create_links()
{
    // If our item count or per-page total is zero there is no need to continue.
    if ($this->total_rows == 0 OR $this->per_page == 0)
    {
       return '';
    }

    // Calculate the total number of pages
    $num_pages = ceil($this->total_rows / $this->per_page);

    // Is there only one page? Hm... nothing more to do here then.
    /*if ($num_pages == 1)
    {
        $info = 'Showing : ' . $this->total_rows;
        return $info;
    }*/

    // Determine the current page number.       
    $CI =& get_instance();  
    if ($CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment) != 0)
    {
        $this->cur_page = $CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment);

        // Prep the current page - no funny business!
        $this->cur_page = (int) $this->cur_page;
    }

    $this->num_links = (int)$this->num_links;

    if ($this->num_links < 1)
    {
        show_error('Your number of links must be a positive number.');
    }

    if ( ! is_numeric($this->cur_page))
    {
        $this->cur_page = 0;
    }

    // Is the page number beyond the result range?
    // If so we show the last page
    if ($this->cur_page > $this->total_rows)
    {
        $this->cur_page = ($num_pages - 1) * $this->per_page;
    }

    $uri_page_number = $this->cur_page;
    $this->cur_page = floor(($this->cur_page/$this->per_page) + 1);

    // Calculate the start and end numbers. These determine
    // which number to start and end the digit links with
    $start = (($this->cur_page - $this->num_links) > 0) ? $this->cur_page - ($this->num_links - 1) : 1;
    $end   = (($this->cur_page + $this->num_links) < $num_pages) ? $this->cur_page + $this->num_links : $num_pages;

    // Add a trailing slash to the base URL if needed
    $this->base_url = rtrim($this->base_url, '/') .'/';

    // And here we go...
    $output = '';

  // SHOWING LINKS
 /* if ($this->show_count)
  {
     $curr_offset = $CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment);
     $info = 'Showing ' . ( $curr_offset + 1 ) . ' to ' ;

     if( ( $curr_offset + $this->per_page ) < ( $this->total_rows -1 ) )
        $info .= $curr_offset + $this->per_page;
     else
        $info .= $this->total_rows;

     $info .= ' of ' . $this->total_rows . ' | ';

     $output .= $info;
  }*/

    // Render the "First" link
    if  ($this->cur_page > $this->num_links)
    {
        $output .= $this->first_tag_open 
                . $this->getAJAXlink( '' , $this->first_link,$this->search_val,$this->start_date,$this->end_date)
                . $this->first_tag_close; 
    }

    // Render the "previous" link
    if  ($this->cur_page != 1)
    {
        $i = $uri_page_number - $this->per_page;
        if ($i == 0) $i = '';
        $output .= $this->prev_tag_open 
                . $this->getAJAXlink( $i, $this->prev_link,$this->search_val,$this->start_date,$this->end_date)
                . $this->prev_tag_close;
    }

    // Write the digit links
    for ($loop = $start -1; $loop <= $end; $loop++)
    {
        $i = ($loop * $this->per_page) - $this->per_page;

        if ($i >= 0)
        {
            if ($this->cur_page == $loop)
            {
                $output .= $this->cur_tag_open.$loop.$this->cur_tag_close; // Current page
            }
            else
            {
                $n = ($i == 0) ? '' : $i;
                $output .= $this->num_tag_open
                    . $this->getAJAXlink( $n, $loop,$this->search_val,$this->start_date,$this->end_date )
                    . $this->num_tag_close;
            }
        }
    }

    // Render the "next" link
    if ($this->cur_page < $num_pages)
    {
        $output .= $this->next_tag_open 
            . $this->getAJAXlink( $this->cur_page * $this->per_page , $this->next_link,$this->search_val,$this->start_date,$this->end_date )
            . $this->next_tag_close;
    }

    // Render the "Last" link
    if (($this->cur_page + $this->num_links) < $num_pages)
    {
        $i = (($num_pages * $this->per_page) - $this->per_page);
        $output .= $this->last_tag_open . $this->getAJAXlink( $i, $this->last_link,$this->search_val,$this->start_date,$this->end_date ) . $this->last_tag_close;
    }

    // Kill double slashes.  Note: Sometimes we can end up with a double slash
    // in the penultimate link so we'll kill all double slashes.
    $output = preg_replace("#([^:])//+#", "\\1/", $output);

    // Add the wrapper HTML if exists
    $output = $this->full_tag_open.$output.$this->full_tag_close;

    return $output;     
}

function getAJAXlink( $count='0', $text,$search_val=0,$start_date=0,$end_date=0) {

    if( $this->div == '')
        return '<a href="'. $this->anchor_class . ' ' . $this->base_url . $count . '">'. $text .'</a>';

    $pageCount = $count?$count:0;
    $this->additional_param = "{'page' : $pageCount,'start_date':'$start_date','end_date':'$end_date','search_val':'$search_val','ajax':'1'}";

    return "<li><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\"
             " . $this->anchor_class . "
                onclick=\"$.post('". $this->base_url . "', ". $this->additional_param .", function(data){
                $('#". $this->div . "').html(data)" . $this->js_rebind ."; }); return false;\">"
            . $text .'</a></li>';
}

}
```

You can include this class and implement in Controller, View, and model as ordinary pagination class.

Comment: This code is for CodeIgniter 1.x.x and won't work for version 3.x.x.